# Handling TimeZones C# Asp.Net MVC SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timezone

This is a tricky scenario so I will try to explain myself well.  We have a system that will have users in different time zones but that will have a program they all participate in that will expire and no longer be visible to them at midnight on a given date.

We are storing the dates in UTC but if we have a user in say India which is I believe 5:30 hours ahead of UTC so if we leave it as UTC for everyone they will be able to see the program for an additional 5:30 hours and if we have a user in Seattle which is -8:00 hours behind the program will end at 4pm.  None of this takes daylight savings into account.

My question is what is the best way to handle this, I have spent hours searching and there are various options none of them ideal.

1. Add an option to their profile for them to select a timezone, will need to be translated, a fair amount of work, etc.  If we allow them to change it they could set to a timezone that allows them to keep seeing items after they should have expired.  Or we set a timezone and they can't change it but not very intuitive if they move, travel, etc.
2. Use the browser to get the offet by javascript, again open to abuse, changing dates, etc.

What is the best way to handle this? how are other people doing it? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both these approaches are acceptable. It depends on wether user's location has an essential role in your program or not. It also depends on how 'virtual' the program is.

For example, if it shows wether some store is open or not than the second approach is better. It is also easier to implement and it really isn't that unreliable.

But if the program is virtual and the midnight is just an agreement than the first approach is better. Of course, it is more difficult to implement, but in the virtual world it looks much better.